# Can I use free EC2 instance while creating cluster with `eksctl` command

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, cloud

I have aws free tier account and I am using `eksctl` to create cluster which also create an EC2 instance, can I pass some parameter in create command to use free EC2 instance.

I am using following command.

```
eksctl create cluster \
--name prod-cluster \
--region us-east-1 \
--nodegroup-name standard-workers \
--node-type t3.medium \
--nodes 3 \
--nodes-min 3 \
--nodes-max 9 \
--managed \
```

Answer (score 1):

eksctl is a simple CLI tool for creating clusters on EKS - Amazon's new managed Kubernetes service for EC2. EKS is not within free tier of AWS. Check this [discussion](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/78).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure weather EKS support free tier or not but if it's supporting by using ec2 instances you can use this

https://eksctl.io/usage/managing-nodegroups/

create node group with respective type of EC2 which supports free tier and add or attach node group to EKS cluster.